# Unriruled subvariety of Fano manifold containing a subvariety and contained in some open dense subset

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective Fano variety of dimension $n$ and $U$ be an open subset of $X$ with $\text{codim}(X-U)$ is at least $3$. Let $Y$ be a smooth projective surface contained in $U$.

Question : Is it possible to find a rational curve through each point of $Y$ which is contained in $U$ ? In other words, does there exist a uniruled projective subvariety containing $Y$ and contained in $U$?

Comment: I don't think your condition "In other words ...." is equivelant. Take a smooth hypersurface of high degree in $\mathbb{CP}^3$ and then delete some non-empty finite set from its complement. Then there is no uniruled projective variety in $U$ containing the hypersurface. However, in this example there still exists the rational curves that you ask for.

Comment: Do you mean there exist rational curve in $U$ through each point of the hypersurface in your example ?

Comment: Do you mean there exist rational curve in $U$ through each point of the hypersurface in your example ?  Anyway your example shows that uniruled projective variety containing $Y$ does not exist.  Can we say something when $Y$ also has high co-dimension in $X$ ?

Comment: Yes. take a point of the hypersurface. There are infinitely many lines in $\mathbb{CP}^3$ containing it. Then after deleting a finite set of points can only remove a finite number of them.

Comment: Yes. I realized that. In fact in your example there is no projective variety in $U$ other than the hypersurface itself containing it.  Can we  say something when $Y$ has high codimension ?